# Debug Asp clássico com visual studio 2017

Tags: asp, visual-studio-2017

Eu não conheço nada de asp clássico e apareceu uma demanda onde tenho que fazer debugging de uma aplicação em asp clássico, pois um dos filtros não estão funcionando. E o response.write/notepad++ não ira me ajudar neste caso, pois já sei que é o retorno do metodo.

Alguém sabe alguma gambiarra para debugar o asp clássico no visual studio 2017 e IIS6 ou 7?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma forma de depurar seria exibir uma mensagem e "matar" o código em seguida, assim você terá certeza que tudo foi executado até o trecho em que você "matou", por exemplo:

```
Response.Write "Rodou até aqui"
Response.End
```

Outra forma é a depuração com o **Visual Studio**, segue abaixo um passo a passo de como faze-la:

1. No **IIS** permita a depuração no lado do servidor:

Clique no seu **Web Site**, clique em **ASP**, no grupo "propriedades de depuração" na linha **Habilitar depuração do servidor** coloque **true** e depois clique em **aplicar**.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2. Abra o projeto no **Visual Studio**, clique em `debug` e depois `attach`:
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
3. Clique no `checkbox`(Visualizar processos de todos os usuários) e selecione o `w3wp`, em seguida clique em `attach`:
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

   3.1 Caso você não tenha aberto o **Visual Studio** como **admin**, reabra ele com as configurações corretas e refaça os passos 2 e 3:
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
4. Clique em `attach` novamente:
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
5. Na **Solution Explorer** você visualizará os fontes do ASP clássico anexados ao processo do IIS, abra o fonte que deseja depurar, coloque o `breakpoint` e acesse o fonte específico através do navegador e pronto:
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]