# Como Debugar ASP clássico no Visual Code

Tags: asp, visual-studio-code

Como debugar ASP clássico no Visual Code, alguma extensão específica pode ser sugerida ou outra forma de configuração para que seja possível debugar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Utilize o VIsual Studio:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297213/debug-asp-cl%C3%A1ssico-com-visual-studio-2017

Answer (score 2):

No Visual Code, o que você vai conseguir é ativar o sintax highlight. Aqui tem um plugin que faz isso:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ilich8086.classic-asp

E aqui tem um passo a passo de como instalar:

https://www.itnota.com/making-visual-studio-code-colorize-classic-asp-code/

Para debugar, você teria que ter o Visual Studio, e configurar o seu IIS. Aqui tem um passo a passo mostrando como isso pode ser feito:

https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/debugging-classic-asp-with-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o Visual studio:

Para depurar, você precisa iniciar o aplicativo com o depurador anexado ao processo do aplicativo. F5 (Depurar > Iniciar Depuração) é a maneira mais comum de fazer isso. No entanto, talvez você ainda não definiu pontos de interrupção para examinar o código do seu aplicativo, portanto faremos isso primeiro e, em seguida, iniciaremos a depuração.

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019

Um exemplo
[Debug Asp clássico com visual studio 2017](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297213/debug-asp-cl%C3%A1ssico-com-visual-studio-2017)